# Exisiting MakeFile Project in Monodevelop

Tags: makefile, monodevelop

Monodevelop has makefile integration, but can it import an existing project generated by cmake (just like in Eclipse CDT's Makefile Project with Existing Code)? If yes, how can I do it?

Sorry, if this is not the right place to ask. They have no forums section.

Comment: please advice if you referring to the mere invocation of exist makefile (how doing so) or how to add files to a new C/C++ solution/project